# U boot send failed: Error when trying to load a u boot image

Tags: linux, boot, embedded, embedded-linux

I am trying to load a uboot image on a PCB. The board uses a pre-configured script in which it attempts to boot the board and, seeing that there is no boot image, it downloads the image over Ethernet to RAM. From RAM, the uboot image is then stored and unpacked on the NAND flash device.

Following download (just before the image is unpacked and installed), I get the following:

```
transfer compleate:
***exit status=0 
/0(STX)/0(CAN) packets, 1 retries, 
loaded 314064 bytes at bfc0ffc0 entry point bfc10000 header 1
```

At this point, I should recieve the following console message:

```
 image loaded. Atttempting to boot 
    d$$$$9e12345
```

However, the script seems to hang and I get this output:

```
drSIU1 loop....done!
SIU2 loop....done!
```

Then, after pausing for a minute or so...

```
  [u boot] u boot send fail
```

I'm not really sure what is going on. The script used to program the board has programmed others successfully so I'm  sure its not exclusivily a coding issue and in fact the problem rests somewhere in the hardware of the PCB.

I have tried changing and reworking all the PCB oscillators, the Xmodem, voltage regulators assocated with RAM, NAND flash and communications interfacing. I have also checked for simple things like dry joints and tombstones within the supporting circuity. I've only limited experence with Linux embedded architecture so would tend to focus on hardware problems.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Many thanks, Tony.

Here is screen shots of the `printenv` command:

[image: printenv 2]
[image: printenv 1]

Here is a transcript of the printenv command call:

```
    SSH AGENT_PID=2835
DH_CONTROL=var/run/xdmctl
GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH=:
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=xfce-
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=386311c5cfa7e46ed4e78bd53a0693f-1526628690.704227-749183263
XDM_MANAGED=method=classic
WINDOWID=12582916
USER=va_pwg
http_proxy=http://proxy.asidua.com:7001
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40:33;01:cd
=40:33;01:or=40:31:01:su=37;41:sug=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;43:ow=34;42:st=34:44:ex=0
1;31:*.

...
...

GLADE MODULE PATH=:
SSH AUTH SOCK=/tmp/ssh.z813AqNFJoIq/agent.2782
ftp proxy=ftp://proxy.asidua.com:2370
SESSION MANAGER=local/bringupBox:@/tmp.ICE.unix/2854,unix/bringupBox:/tmp.ICE-
unix/2854
XDG CONFIG DIRS=/etc/xdg
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
DESKTOP SESSION=defult
PWD=/home/va_pwg/bringup
LANG=en GB.UTF-8
https proxy=https://proxy.asidua.com:7001
HOME=/home/va_pwg
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=va_pwg
XDG DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share
DBUS_DESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus=9xH3fy9qEV,guid=d4b481295fd992c
6ce8931e75afe8154
WINDOWPATH=7
DISPLAY=:0.0
GLADE_CATALOG_PATH=:
LIBGLADE_MODULE_PATH=:
COLORTERM=Terminal
OLDPWD=/home/va_pwg/bringup
    =/usr/bin/printenv
```